# Open ng-bootstrap Modal from Compontent

Tags: typescript, angular5, ng-bootstrap

I have a angular5 component that should trigger a bootstrap model to open. It works well using a button but no clear api documentation on how to open ng-bootstrap modal (bootstrap 4) programatically inside a component.

sample-modal.ts

```
constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

open(content){
 this.modalService.open(content);
}
```

sample-modal.html

```
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: is there any error .?

Answer (score 7):

Angular 9 Version

**Template**

```
<ng-template #myModal let-modal>
    <h1>My Modal</h1>
</ng-template>
```

**Component**

```
@ViewChild('myModal') myModal : any;

openModal() {
    this.modalService.open(this.myModal);
}
```

Comment: What does let-modal mean in ng-template?  I have only seen it  as let-id="myId"? In ng-template what does let-modal equals to?

Comment: @bluejimmy I am not sure what it means but can confirm it is also in the basic docs for ng-bootstrap modal as of 1/7/22.  https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples#component

Answer (score 5):

You need to do this.

```
  @ViewChild('content') content : any;
  modalRef: BsModalRef;

  private modalConfig: ModalOptions = {
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: true,
    class: 'modal-md',
  };

  show() {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(this.content, this.modalConfig);
  }

  hide() {
    this.modalRef.hide();
  }
```

even you can make it as a separate reusable component and using ng-content to pass content of modal to that component

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a separate modal component and add it to the entry components for it to work in this manner.

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples